# Most efficient way to average bunches of x embeddings from a Tensorflow variable that contains y total embeddings

Tags: python, tensorflow

Say that I have y total embeddings which were retrieved using this code

```
embeds = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embeddings, train_dataset)
```

So the data would look something like this

```
embeds = [embed45, embed2, embed939, embed3, embed32, embed2, . . . etc]
```

And lets say, I want to take the average of groups of 3 embeddings. So something like

```
averaged_embeds = [ averageOf(embed45, embed2, embed939) , averageOf(embed3, embed32, embed2), . . . . etc]
```

so when evaluated it'll look something like this

```
averaged_embeds = [ averagedEmbeds1, averagedEmbeds2, averagedEmbeds3, . . . etc]
```

What is the best way to go about doing that?

My first thought was tf.segment_mean but as far as I can tell, it can only take averages within each of the embeddings, it doesn't average a bunch of embeddings (let me know if this is wrong).

There is also tf.reduce_mean which can averages along a specified dimension, but it'll take the average across all embeddings, not bunches of a particular number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`tf.split`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/split), but that would mean, the param `num_or_size_splits` should be a multiple of length of the input if its a scalar, or the sum of the dimensions along the split dimensions should match with the length of the input (same for [`tf.segment_mean`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/segment_mean) as well). A better approach is to use `tf.extract_image_patches` where those restrictions dont apply:

```
# generate batch of inputs
def get_batch(tensor, batch, k):
    return tf.extract_image_patches(tensor, 
                                ksizes=[1, batch, k, 1], 
                                strides=[1, batch, k, 1], 
                                rates=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='VALID')


embed_dim = 5
batch = 3
x = np.arange(200).reshape(-1, embed_dim)

embeddings = tf.constant(x)
train_dataset = tf.constant([0,1,2,5,6,7])
embeds = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embeddings, train_dataset)


split = tf.reshape(get_batch(embeds[None,..., None], batch, embed_dim),
                   [-1, batch, embed_dim])
avg = tf.reduce_mean(split, 1)

with tf.Session() as sess:
   print(sess.run(embeds))
   #[[ 0  1  2  3  4]
   # [ 5  6  7  8  9]
   # [10 11 12 13 14]
   # [25 26 27 28 29]
   # [30 31 32 33 34]
   # [35 36 37 38 39]]

   print(sess.run(split))
   #[[[ 0  1  2  3  4]
   # [ 5  6  7  8  9]
   # [10 11 12 13 14]]

   # [[25 26 27 28 29]
   #  [30 31 32 33 34]
   #  [35 36 37 38 39]]]

   print(sess.run(avg))
   #[[ 5  6  7  8  9]
   # [30 31 32 33 34]]
```

For 3D segments the code changes to:

```
 dim1 = 2
 x = np.arange(200).reshape(-1, dim1, embed_dim)
 split = tf.reshape(get_batch(embeds[None,...], batch, dim1),
                    [-1, batch, dim1, embed_dim])
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually tf.segment_mean can be used to average embeddings, here's an example

```
%matplotlib inline
from __future__ import print_function
import collections
import math
import numpy as np
import os
import random
import tensorflow as tf
import zipfile
from matplotlib import pylab
from six.moves import range
from six.moves.urllib.request import urlretrieve

tf.enable_eager_execution() 

train_dataset = [3, 7, 5 ,12 ,19 ,6, 10, 8]

embeddings = tf.get_variable( 'generator', 
    initializer=tf.random_uniform([20, 6], -1.0, 1.0))

embed = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embeddings, train_dataset)

print(embed)

segments= np.arange(2).repeat(4)
print(segments)

averaged_embeds = tf.segment_mean( embed, segments, name=None)
print(averaged_embeds)

#Use this to confirm that the embeddings were averaged correctly
print( np.mean([   -0.78844213 ,  -0.2852435 , 0.58107734, 0.12990952   ]))
```

Unfortunately, I have yet to find a way to take averages if the embed tensor has more than two dimensions. I tried using `segments` that have more than one dimension but it doesn't seem to work out. So far now I reshape the `embed` and `segments` tensors before and after the `tf.segment_mean` operation.